# Ionic - bar footer css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to get rid of border on bar footer in Ionic, but I still have white lines on top and bottom of bar-subfooter and I don't know how to get rid of it:

This is my css:

```
.introduction {
  i {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: $white;
    line-height: 190px;
  }

  .icon-circle {
    background-color: $darkgray;
    width:190px;
    height: 190px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 85px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .info {
    margin: 50px 30px 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.bar-footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $dark-background-color;
  border: 0;

  a {
    margin:auto;
    color: $white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.bar-subfooter {
  border: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 74px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<ion-content class="introduction">

    <div class="icon-circle">
      <i class="ion-thumbsup"></i>
    </div>

  <div class="info">
    <h3>Som ansatt i Coop har du nå tilgang til interne nyheter via din mobil. </h3>
  </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-subfooter">
  <input type="submit" class="button button-next button-positive" value="Neste">
</ion-footer-bar>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer">
  <a ui-sref="main.front">Hopp over introduksjon</a>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footer works with a `background-image` instead of `border`

```
.bar-footer{
      background-image:'none';
}
```